# itunesconnect - 'New Version' button not available

Tags: app-store-connect

How to add a new version of the app in iTunesConnect ? The button is not  available, please see the below screenshot.

[image]

I found a link to tour where it is given that you can add a new version using the button `+ Version or Platform` as shown below. But, this button is **disabled** for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to contact Apple to resolve this problem. It was an issue with iTunesConnect.

Comment: So there is nothing to be done other than to contact Apple and ask them to fix it?

Comment: @ComDubh Yes, they said that there was a bug in the system and they would fix it.

Comment: I also contacted Apple. At first they attributed the disabled "+ version" option to something that I had done, but then said it was a "trending issue" that other developers were having and that their engineers were working on a fix.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create a new version if you already have a 'developer rejected' version. I suspect you can't create a new version either when you have one 'Ready for Sale' as in the original posting. You can however upload a new build, which is probably what you want to do anyway. Go to the page for the app in iTunes Connect, hover over the Build, click the red bar to delete it (this latter option is what I had missed myself). Now you can upload a new build from XCode (or use one you uploaded already) and add it to this version.

Answer (score 2):

As Apple has no solution, then we will force add new versión, this work for me:

From the iTunes connect page for the app version you wish to create a new version:

[image]

- Should be **use** Chrome developer tools or firefox **inspector**.
- Select the **source** for the page and open the **find dialog** (CTRL+F).
- **Search** for "platform in newVersionPlatformList".
- This will show the enclosing "li" of the button (iOS or tvOS). Find all childs "a" tags, which should look something like this: `<a href="" ng-show="(platform.exists === undefined || platform.exists === null) &amp;&amp; !platform.disabled &amp;&amp; !canCreateVersions" ng-click="showContractModal()" class="ng-binding ng-hide">iOS</a>`
- Must **remove** class "ng-hide" of "a" tags and this will show another (iOS or tvOS) button in browser.

[image]
 - In the browser, must try to **click** on the new buttons (iOS or tvOS) and this will show popup the dialog of new version number.

[image]

- Enter new version number

[image]

Comment: This worked for me.  I used Firebug to achieve the same result.

Comment: Worked for me too, but what is going on? why aren't the buttons working?

Comment: This doesn't work. It says 'Forbidden' when I try to add a new verision.

Answer (score 0):

1. "(+) VERSION OR PLATFORM" botton is showing?
2. Which browser you are using? Use Safari.
3. If there is an update on the contract / license agreement, you have to review and approve.

[image]

Comment: Please see updated image in my question. The "VERSION OR PLATFORM" button is disabled. I have checked and there is no update on contract. Thanks for your help