# The button IOS into Add platform or version is not working, Cannot upload a new version to the AppStore using ITUNES CONNECT

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I don't know what is happening with Itunes Connect, I cannot upload a new version of my application. The problem is that the button IOS into the *Add New version or platform* doesn't work!!!

I click on the '*Add New version or platform*' and it show me the popup, but when I press on the *ios* item, nothing happens I inspected the web of the Itunes and it just throw me css warning. [See the image attached, as you can see the button is disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PYpR.png)

I really need to upload the new version to production, there is a big bug that need to be resolved as soon as posible.[enter image description here]

**UPDATE**

It is a bug of Itunes connect. Apple will fix, but a quick solution to this issue is explained in the response to this post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [itunesconnect - 'New Version' button not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32772957/itunesconnect-new-version-button-not-available)

Comment: @AliBeadle It is not the same question, The button that is disable is the IOS button not the 'add platform or version', This button appears when the -'add version or platform' is clicked. Also this problems appeared yesterday, because I uploaded successfully the las week.

Comment: Understood that the original question is not exactly the same. But are any of the other answers to that question relevant or helpful? Notably that you do not normally use that button to upload a new version but rather push a new version from XCode.

Comment: Unfortunatelly no, it is really weird, I already sent  a message to the itunes' stuff.

Comment: What happens if you try to upload a new version from XCode without using that button in iTunes Connect?

Comment: also have you tried (from the other linked question) "Go to the page for the app in iTunes Connect, hover over the Build, click the red bar to delete it (this latter option is what I had missed myself). Now you can upload a new build from XCode (or use one you uploaded already) and add it to this version."

Comment: @AliBeadle I tried but it didn't work. I will try upload using fastlane.

Comment: @AliBeadle I found a solution, take a look at my solution. Looks like a bug of Itunes Connect.

Comment: 2017 and this problem still getting on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple reply me that they will take care about it, but they didn't say that it is a bug of their page. I coudln't wait for a solution from apple so I inspected the elements of the web an try to find out a way to solve my problem, and finally I found it!!

**The solution**

[Image of the DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahBRC.png)

As you can see in the image there are a list of < a > where only two of them the ng-show is true, so my solution is delete the < a > where the ng-show contains the attribute *!canCreateVersions* and into the first < a > delete the ng-show attribute, and the ng-hide class, so the button that works is the first that appears in the first place of the list where the ng-click action is *openVersionModal*.

```
<a href="" ng-click="openVersionModal(platform.platform)" class="ng-binding ">iOS</a>
```

The li should looks like this :

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wap1W.png)

Comment: I had to try a couple of times before it worked, but it eventually did as promised.